# The most idiomatic adjective for a community that is not well established

Tags: word-request

> Unlike in Western European countries were scientific community has
>   developed for a couple of centuries, scientific community in this
>   country is yet ______ and fragile.

I want to say that the community is not established for a very long time and so is not well established and not well-developed.

I thought of elementary, primitive, and seminal. But I am looking for the most idiomatic word for such context.

Answer (score 4):

I quite like **fledgling** for this:

> **[Fledgling](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fledgling)**:
>   adjective [ before noun ]
>   uk ​ /ˈfledʒlɪŋ/ us ​ (also fledgeling)
>
> a fledgling company or industry is a fairly new one with little experience in a business activity:
>   Many fledgling companies need financial assistance.
>   One of those fledgeling industries in the area is tourism.
>   a fledgling airline/brewery/bank

...but it may require rearrangement of your sentence a little, e.g.:

> The **fledgling** scientific community in this country is fragile, compared to those in Western European countries, which have developed for a couple of centuries.

Some words that might fit directly in your sentence *without* rearrangement, are:

- **unrefined**, **unsophisticated** or **inexperienced**

Your existing suggestion of *primitive* isn't a bad choice, either.

Comment: **Fledgling** is a very good choice, especially if you're looking for a neutral term.  Most of the other alternatives are somewhat more negative (or even pejorative if used carelessly).

Answer (score 2):

**Nascent**

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nascent):

> Beginning to exist or develop

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nascent):

> Nascent things or processes are just beginning, and are expected to become stronger or to grow bigger.